# why copy constructor is getting called even though I am actually copying to already created object in C++?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I wrote below code and I didn't understand why copy constructor is getting called.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class abc
{
    public:
        abc()
        {
            cout << "in Construcutor" << (this) << endl;
        };

        ~abc()
        {
            cout << "in Destrucutor" << (this) << endl;
        };

        abc(const abc &obj)
        {
            cout << "in copy constructor" << (this) << endl;
            cout << "in copy constructor src " << &obj << endl;
        }

        abc& operator=(const abc &obj)
        {
            cout << "in operator =" << (this) << endl;
            cout << "in operator = src " << &obj << endl;
        }
};

abc myfunc()
{
    static abc tmp;

    return tmp;
}

int main()
{
    abc obj1;

    obj1 = myfunc();

    cout << "OK. I got here" << endl;
}
```

when I ran this program, I am getting the following output

```
in Construcutor0xbff0e6fe
in Construcutor0x804a100
in copy constructor0xbff0e6ff
in copy constructor src 0x804a100
in operator =0xbff0e6fe
in operator = src 0xbff0e6ff
in Destrucutor0xbff0e6ff
OK. I got here
in Destrucutor0xbff0e6fe
in Destrucutor0x804a100
```

I didn't understand why copy constructor is getting called when I was actually assigning the object.

If I declare `abc tmp`, instead of `static abc tmp` in `myfunc()`, then copy constructor is not getting called. Can any one please help me to understand what is going on here.

Comment: Because that’s exactly what a copy constructor does.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because you return an object *by value* from `myfunc`, which means it's getting copied.

The reason the copy-constructor is not getting called if you don't make the object `static` in `myfunc` is because of [*copy elision*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision) and [*return value optimization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) (a.k.a. RVO). Note that even though your copy-constructor may not be called, it still has to exist.

Comment: I always thought optimization is there to optimize stuff *behind the scenes*. RVO seems to drastically change the program by possibly eliding constructors. Why does the standard allow such implementation-defined behavior and not enforce either RVO or no RVO at all?

Comment: @cad In the case of the non-static object being returned, that object would be destroyed anyway, why bother copying it when the copying can be elided? It *does* make a difference if the copy-constructor have some side-effects besides actually copy the data, like printing output, but not otherwise. The `static` local variable *must* be copied "properly", because it will still exist after the call.

Comment: As to why the standard does not either mandate or forbid RVO, at the time of the original standard I think some implementers would have struggled to implement it (which meant mandating it would be hard), but it can provide a massive performance enhancement (which means forbidding it is annoying).  Permitting (but not requiring) copy constructor + destructor elision was a good compromise.  (I believe there is a proposal that RVO *should* be mandated in an upcoming version of the standard.)

Comment: The standard says (not in so many words) that the compiler is allowed to assume that copy constructor and copy assignment do (and only do) those operations and optimize accordingly. The take away is that you should never rely on these operations to do anything else unless you are okay with it not being done (optimized away).